# Copying multiple files in large volume between two s3 buckets which are in the different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I need to copy a large chunk of data, around 300 GB of files from say bucket A which is in us-east region and to bucket B which is in ap-southeast region. Also I need to change the structure of the bucket. Like I need to push the files to different folders on bucket B according to the image name which is in the bucket A. I tried to using AWS Lambda but it's not available in ap-southeast.

Also how much would it cost since data will be transferred between regions?

Answer (score 1):

**Method**

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has the `aws s3 cp` command that can be used to move objects between buckets (even in different regions), and can rename them at the same time.

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-in-us/foo/bar.txt s3://bucket-in-ap/foo1/foo2/bar3.txt
```

There is also the `aws s3 sync` option that can be used to synchronize content between two buckets, but that doesn't help your requirement to rename objects.

**Cost**

Data Transfer charges from US regions to another region are shown on the [Amazon S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) as US$0.02/GB.

Comment: My understanding (and my tests) show that syncing between buckets *does not* go via the local machine. For example. I copied a 200MB object between buckets in Sydney and Tokyo -- it took 37 seconds. When merely *downloading* the object from Sydney (where I live), it took 3 minutes. Try it for yourself: Grab some sample data from this public dataset: `s3://landsat-pds/L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/`

Comment: Thanks for the correction John. From the `aws s3` documentation it seemed like the command is actually using local storage as a cache. I'll delete my original comment.

Comment: I'd still recommend using the cross-region replication since it deals with ongoing changes so you don't have to manage the split-brain scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use bucket replication and then create another bucket in your target region and do your S3 object key manipulation.

Read more on [S3 cross-region replication](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/).